# Entity Framework Core Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ef-core-3.0

I use EntityFrameworkCore for a Discord Bot with a MySQL Database. In itself everything works very well, but every time I access the `DbContext`, some objects are created that are never disposed again. In the Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools after a few database queries it looks like this:
[image]

This is how I integrate the Entity Framework into my program:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection().AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(x => x.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=testdb;user=root"));
```

This calls my extension method:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection This,
            Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsBuilder)
            where TContext : DbContext
        {
            return This
                .AddSingleton(x =>
                {
                    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
                    optionsBuilder(builder);
                    return builder.Options;
                })
                .AddTransient<TContext>()
                .AddTransient<DbContext>(x => x.GetRequiredService<TContext>());
        }
```

My `DatabaseContext` looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<GuildEntity> Guilds { get; set; }

     public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
                : base(options)
     {
     }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          modelBuilder.Entity<GuildEntity>(entity =>
          {
              entity.Property(x => x.Level).HasDefaultValue(true);

              entity.Property(x => x.Notify).HasDefaultValue(false);

              entity.Property(x => x.Log).HasDefaultValue(false);

              entity.Property(x => x.Trash).HasDefaultValue(false);
          });
     }
}
```

I also have this `DatabaseService` with which I get the `DatabaseContext`:

```
public class DatabaseService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DatabaseService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public TContext Open<TContext>() where TContext : DbContext
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TContext>();
    }
}
```

And this is the way I do a database query:

```
using (var db = _databaseService.Open<DatabaseContext>())
{
    var guilds = db.Guilds.Where(p => p.GuildName == "MyGuild");
}
```

Even if I include an `AsNoTracking()` in the query, objects are created for this query that are never disposed.

I have absolutely no idea where my mistake is, I hope my examples are enough to see the mistake. If not, here is the GitHub repository of my Discord Bot: [Code of my bot](https://github.com/xSwaight/Rabbot.Net)